# How to hide the letters of a password while typing

Tags: android

I am dealing an application with Android. My requirement is hiding  password while user is typing the password. I know how to hide the password but the password what the user typing is visible for a while before converting into unreadable format.Can anyone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the default edit text property as **password**. Instead, you can use `addTextChangedListener()` which will get called as soon as the user enters a character. Maintain an activity level string say "mPass". In the `TextWatcher()`, `onTextChanged` method, append character to your mPass and replace the input character by *.

But you will have to be careful regarding this coz application will pass control to the `TextWatcher()` even after you have replaced the character by *. If not handled properly it will get called recursively causing the application to crash.

Tedious way, but it will work...

Comment: then suggest a better method @DINITHRUKSHANKUMARA

Answer (score 13):

Implementation of TransformationMethod to hide the letters of a password while typing:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // example of usage
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.password)).setTransformationMethod(new HiddenPassTransformationMethod());
}

private class HiddenPassTransformationMethod implements TransformationMethod {

    private char DOT = '\u2022';

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(final CharSequence charSequence, final View view) {
        return new PassCharSequence(charSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChanged(final View view, final CharSequence charSequence, final boolean b, final int i,
                               final Rect rect) {
        //nothing to do here
    }

    private class PassCharSequence implements CharSequence {

        private final CharSequence charSequence;

        public PassCharSequence(final CharSequence charSequence) {
            this.charSequence = charSequence;
        }

        @Override
        public char charAt(final int index) {
            return DOT;
        }

        @Override
        public int length() {
            return charSequence.length();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence subSequence(final int start, final int end) {
            return new PassCharSequence(charSequence.subSequence(start, end));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wow. this is amazing. Working better than expected. Thanks a lot !!! This should be the correct answer & also the best.

Answer (score 1):

a much easier why is to add this to your xml file:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that only the last character or the first character (if charsequence length == 1) is shown (not masked) as you type.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // example of usage
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.password)).setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
}
public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private static class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            // Only the last character or the first character if length == 1 is visible to the user
            return (mSource.length() == index + 1) ? mSource.charAt(index) : '*'; 
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        @NotNull
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is attribute for TextView in android:

> android:password Whether
>   the characters of the field are displayed as password dots instead of
>   themselves.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:password](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3apassword)

Answer (score -1):

set `android:password="true"`. It will do what you expect.

Example:

```
   <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:password="true" />
```

Comment: Mr.Mechanic, I am aware of this. But my requirement is different.Please go through the post once again.

Answer (score -2):

Just go into general, security, then scroll till you find 'make passwords visible' (show password characters briefly when you type them) this will stop the letters coming up for a short period of time and will reduce the chances of someone reading your password when you type it in.

Comment: OP wants a solution on the application side, not based on phone settings.