# Android password fields - input hidden at all times

Tags: java, android, passwords

As most of you know, at the moment, the password field works in a way that it hides the input, but not right away. As you input a character, it shows that character, then a moment later turns it into a `*`, I'm wondering if there's a way to incorporate a functionality that makes the characters stars at all times.

Any ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the default edit text property as password. Instead, you can use `addTextChangedListener()` which will get called as soon as the user enters a character. Maintain an activity level string say "mPass". In the `TextWatcher()`, `onTextChanged` method, append character to your mPass and replace the input character by *.

But you will have to be careful regarding this because application will pass control to the `TextWatcher()` even after you have replaced the character by *. If not handled properly it will get called recursively causing the application to crash.

Credit to [Pallavi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13268613)

Comment: Thanks, I just looked it up myself. Should have given Pallavi credit :) Either way, this seems to be the solution.

Comment: I was going to give credit, I was answering on my phone:)